Launching app from postinst installing .rpm(making by cpack)
I want to start my new installed from .rpm app after installing my rpm-package.
I have a script that works in console -
login with root and run it - it launches my app by active user and I can close console and app will stay working
but when I paste this code in postinst it doesn't works... (app doesn't launch after install) What's wrong?
function run_app
{
    xhost +SI:localuser:"$1"
    pkexec --user $1 env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR myapp 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
}

#запуск приложения для активных пользователей (у кого запущена X-сессия)
active_users=$(users)
for user in $active_users; do
    echo $user
    nohup $(run_app "$user") &
done

